# CSS Animation - Let images fade in one after another

Tags: html, css, typo3, css-animations

I have a row of pictures where I want to fade in one image after another.

```
 .jumbotron > div > div picture > img{

animation: fadein 6s;
-moz-animation: fadein 6s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: fadein 6s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: fadein 6s; /* Opera */

 }

 @keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

This code let's all images fade in at the same time.

I'm using typo3 with a template, the html structure is a bit complicated because of this - I'm sorry.

```
<section class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">

<div id="c1170" class="">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class=" ">
<div id="c1163" class="">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<div class=" ">
<div id="c1164" class="">
<div class="ce-textpic ce-left ce-above">
<div class="" >
 <div class="row">
 <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 ">
 <div class="ce-media">
 <picture alt="Geigen3D_m_02.gif">
 <video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
 <![CDATA[ orig Width: 123px ]]>
 <![CDATA[ xs scale: 0.5, 544px, max: 272px]]>
 <source srcset="fileadmin/images/buecher/erzaehlungen/Geigen3D_m_02.gif" media="(max-width: 544px)">
 <![CDATA[ sm scale: 0.5, 768px, max: 384px]]>
 <source srcset="fileadmin/images/buecher/erzaehlungen/Geigen3D_m_02.gif" media="(max-width: 768px)">
 <![CDATA[ md scale: 0.125, 992px, max: 124px]]>
 <source srcset="fileadmin/images/buecher/erzaehlungen/Geigen3D_m_02.gif" media="(max-width: 992px)">
 <![CDATA[ lg scale: 0.125, 1200px, max: 150px]]>
 <source srcset="fileadmin/images/buecher/erzaehlungen/Geigen3D_m_02.gif" media="(min-width: 992px)">
 </video><![endif]-->
 <img src="fileadmin/images/buecher/erzaehlungen/Geigen3D_m_02.gif"
 alt="Geigen3D_m_02.gif "
 title=""
 class="img-fluid m-b-1 " />
 </picture>
 </div>

 </div>

 <div class="clearfix hidden-sm-up"></div>



 <div class="hidden-xs-down clearfix hidden-md-up"></div>



 <div class="hidden-sm-down clearfix hidden-lg-up"></div>



 <div class="hidden-md-down clearfix hidden-xl-up"></div>



 <div class="hidden-lg-down clearfix"></div>



 </div>
</div>

<div class="ce-bodytext">


</div>

</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<div class=" ">

<div id="c1165" class="">
<div class="ce-textpic ce-left ce-above">
<div class="" >
 <div class="row">
 <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 ">


 <div class="ce-media">




<!--next picture begins-->

 <picture alt="image.gif">
```

and so on, and so on...

All solutions are welcome (pure css solution would be great tho), thank you for reading!

Comment: Is `JavaScript` an option?

Comment: Pure css would be great, but if that's not possible JavaScript is an option - yes!

Comment: is length of pictures array known?

Comment: Different type of animation but the method would be pretty much the same as the one used here (if the no. of pictures is known) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568319/expand-circles-sequentially-using-css/33568849#33568849. If the no. of pictures is unknown then you'd most likely have to use scripting.

Comment: Currently there are 6 pictures, but the editor may want to add more pictures or delete...

Comment: here is one more solution for known number of elements: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41593166/4206079

Comment: Hmm. What exactly could I do if the number of elements is unknown?

Comment: so you need to use Javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only solution using an approach similar to what you're starting with. I've simplified the HTML and CSS to focus on the important parts.

**The General Idea**

Layout your images as you desire. In this case I've used a `<ul>` element with `<li>` elements to hold the images, and laid them out horizontally.

Add a `fadeIn` animation to the images.

Now here's the key, add a `animation-delay` for each image, dependent on it's number in the lineup. The first will have no delay. The 2nd, a 3 second delay. The 3rd, a 6 second delay, and so on. This timing comes from the `animation-duration` of 3s. After the first image has faded in, the 2nd will fade in. After the 2nd has faded in, the 3rd will fade in, etc, etc.

**Unknown Number of Images?**

If the number of images is unknown this approach can still be used, though it will mean creating a few CSS styles that may never be used. You'll need to create:

```
li:nth-child(N) > img {
  animation-delay: [animation-duration * N]s;
}
```

for the maximum number of images you think you'll have. So if you might have 100 images, and the `animation-duration` is set to 3s, you'll create 100 of those snippets, all the way through:

```
li:nth-child(100) > img {
  animation-delay: 300s;
}
```

**Demo**

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li:nth-child(2) > img {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

li:nth-child(3) > img {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

li:nth-child(4) > img {
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

li:nth-child(5) > img {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

li:nth-child(6) > img {
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

li:nth-child(7) > img {
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

li:nth-child(8) > img {
  animation-delay:21s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400?text=1" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400?text=2" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400?text=3" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400?text=4" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400?text=5" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400?text=6" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400?text=7" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400?text=8" /></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the same demo on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/mRPqVY).

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you getting any animations to work?

Comment: Have a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpKrWN It fades in all the pictures at the same time. #c1163 > div > div:nth-child(6){display:none} I tried this to be sure I have the right child selected and this worked, but it just ignores the animation delay... Did I miss something?

Comment: Your selectors are incorrect. You need to make sure you'll applying the `animation-delay` to the img, but as is your selectors aren't doing that. You apply the `animation` with a `.column-image > div picture > img` selector. But then apply the `animation` delay with `#c1163 > div > div:nth-child(2)`, when it should be something like `.column-image > div:nth-child(2) picture > img`

Comment: That Codepen is incomplete btw, maybe you need to do a Save. It only contains CSS.

Comment: Now it's working! I posted CSS only on purpose, because the html code is huge and contains a lot of white space, because of typo3. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is to add an animation delay to every img (div in my example) increasingly. divs start with `opacity:0;` , attached in a class in this case, then we need some JavaScript to remove that opacity property once the animation has finished.

```js
$('div').on('animationend', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('initial');
})
```

```css
.initial {
  opacity: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  animation: fadein 6s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 6s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 6s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadein 6s;
  /* Opera */
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  /* Firefox */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  /* Opera */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="initial"></div>
<div class="initial"></div>
<div class="initial"></div>
<div class="initial"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```