# CSS transition: opacity not kicking in .

Tags: css, image, fade

I was trying to implement a slideshow with fade-in and fade-out images.

But the basic thing of fading in just won't work for me.
The opacity attribute works fine.
It's the transition of opacity that is stuck.

I'm on an old PC with XP SP3, if that makes any difference.
I've been using Firefox and Chrome as browsers.
But I've been able to see other people's fade fiddles on this PC.
So I'm curious as to why my [fade-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trunk/xky9bug4/) doesn't run as planned.

All ideas towards the right path welcome.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <title>Test Fade</title>

    <body>
  <br/>
  <br/>
    
        <div class="fade-div" >
    <img class="fade-in" src="https://atlassociety.org/images/marilyn-monroe-ayn-rand-admired.jpg" />
        </div>

    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
       background-position: center center;
       text-align: center;
       width: 250px;
       height: 250px;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .fade-div {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
    }

    img {
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;

   }

   .fade-in {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 2s linear;
   }
```

Comment: You aren't actually doing anything to apply the transition.

Comment: do you need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41593166/4206079  but with pictures

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a starting opacity, and then transition to another opacity when something happens.

Hover over the image to see this in action...

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/5yq1bu1v/)

```css
body {
  background-position: center center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
#fadeDiv {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
#fadeDiv:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fadeDiv">
  <img class="fade-in" src="https://atlassociety.org/images/marilyn-monroe-ayn-rand-admired.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To trigger the transition you have to set a new `opacity`. Adding a `hover` pseudo selector is an easy way to do this, you can also change the opacity programmatically in JS:

```css
body {
  background-position: center center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
 
#fadeDiv {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

/* changes opacity on hover and triggers transition */
img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.fade-in{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <title>Test Fade</title>
  <body>
    <div id="fadeDiv" >
      <img class="fade-in" src="https://atlassociety.org/images/marilyn-monroe-ayn-rand-admired.jpg" />
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answers. I needed something more automatic than a hover activated transition. I used a short JS script and - as long as I take the timings of transitions into account - it works acceptably enough. I'd show you the finished code if only JSFiddle was working reliably but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution using element background change with fade In-Out effect:

```css
body {background-position: center center;
         text-align: center;
       width: 250px;
         height: 250px;
         margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
        }

#fadeDiv{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}

.fade-in {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://atlassociety.org/images/marilyn-monroe-ayn-rand-admired.jpg");
    animation: bgFadeInOut 8s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes bgFadeInOut {
    0% {
       background-image: url("https://atlassociety.org/images/marilyn-monroe-ayn-rand-admired.jpg");
    }
    34% {
       background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-200-200-7.jpg");
    }
    66% {
       background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-200-200-1.jpg");
   }
    100% {
       background-image: url("https://atlassociety.org/images/marilyn-monroe-ayn-rand-admired.jpg");
    }

}
```

```html
   <body>
  <br/>
  <br/>

        <div id="fadeDiv" >
    <div class="fade-in"></div>
        </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted by your advice.

**HTML/JS**

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test Fade</title>
        <link href="css/test2-style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript">function fadeInOut()
        {
            var img = document.getElementById("photo");
            setInterval(function()
            {
                img.className = "fade-in"; // Fade in over 2 secs
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    img.className = "fade-out"; // Fade out after 2 secs
                }, 2000);
            }, 4000); // Cycle whole process every 4 secs
        }
        </script>
    
        <body onload="fadeInOut()">
            <br/>
            <br/>
    
            <div class="fade-div">
                <img id="photo" class="" width="200" height="200" 
                src="https://www.gannett-cdn.com/presto/2018/10/01/USAT/d806e46a-c0b6-4ffb-84a3-8dfad6a3447b-AP_Marilyn_Monroe_Auction.JPG" />
            </div>
        
    </html>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-position: center center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
.fade-div{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

img{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.fade-in{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

.fade-out{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
```